# Is there a point where null hypothesis testing is superflous?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

Say you're writing a paper and you have the following data

[image]

Each bar represents an average over a 120 values. I want to determine if the left five and right five sets of data are significantly different from each other, e.g. left datapoint one vs right datapoint one and so forth.

The smallest difference is the fourth data point respectively, with the left being about 1.9 times bigger than the right.

Is it common to perform a null hypothesis testing for a difference this (apparently) significant?

Or, asked differently, is it conceivable to have data where you would have to accept the null hypothesis even though the data looks to be this skewed, especially over 120 samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, the whole point of hypothesis testing is to formalize concepts like "this looks significant" by actually giving some meaning to what "looks significant" means, so yes, you should pretty much always do hypothesis testing if your goal
is to test a hypothesis, of which testing difference between means is certainly an example. There is one valid caveat: if your goal is to only say things about the sample of data you collected and make statements about that sample, then you don't need to test, the observed differences are the true differences (of that sample). Hypothesis testing, in a imprecise way, is about generalizing the observed results to a larger population. If you had a sample of 1st graders and wanted to know if the boys or girls are older on average, you can just compare the means and no need to test anything, but if you wanted to use that data to say something about the average age difference first graders by gender in a more general setting, then you need need to test your hypothesis.

To answer your specific question, you can of course have situations where you could fail to reject the null even when you observe such a difference, and indeed, for any difference, you can easily think of data that can show that result without it existing. In particular, notice that you are looking at sample means, and you're missing the fact that you may be dealing with data that has large variance.

To illustrate concretely, here's a really simple example in `R`:

```
> set.seed(132)
> x = rnorm(120, mean = 0, sd = 100)
> y = rnorm(120, mean = 0, sd = 100)
> mean(x)
[1] 3.754229
> mean(y)
[1] 7.399619
```

They are both 120 draws from the same normal distribution with mean and variance, and the observed mean of y is about two times that of x! Of course, if you tested this, the sample variances would be huge, and so you'd fail to reject the null. Indeed, we have:

```
> t.test(x,y)

Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x and y
t = -0.28222, df = 235.34, p-value = 0.778
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -29.09253  21.80175
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 3.754229  7.399619
```

We fail to reject the null at any reasonable level (pval = .78). So yes, test -- things that seem "obvious" by looking at features of the data (such as means) ignore a lot of information about the data.

Comment: Now that you say it, it seems obvious that such data exists. I suppose you can get tunnel vision on the data you're analyzing. I agree with you. Would you say a histogram like this could substitute a deeper analysis: https://i.imgur.com/GAFas2T.png ? Sorry that I'm being so hardheaded about this, doing a Mann-Whitney U Test isn't a big deal, it just feels like shooting at sparrows with cannons.

Comment: @Marv The same thing can happen.. I can think of having a skewed distribution and a more normal looking one with the same mean that have differences like that with 120 observations. Depending on your problem, 120 observations may  be a lot, or it may be nothing. It depends on what the point of this difference is in your project, but if you want to claim that they are different and want to then use that difference, then you should report it. If you tell me the difference is important, then you should tell me there is a significant difference and not just noise, and graphs don't accomplish that.

Comment: Especially with histogram plots... for all I know, there is some value of 1000 for the dark density, and it doesn't show up in the histogram because its just one or two such values, but that may fundamentally affect the mean. Now you may say "but the means are also the same as in the other figure" at which point I'd point out that all this indirect proof is a lot like shooting sparrows with cannons when you can just formally test it with one line of code ;)

Comment: Fair enough! I'll include it. By the way, Whitney U resulted in a p value of 1.966158e-124 :-)